# SQL Grand total without subtotals

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollup

I'm making a large SQL report in Orderwise, very roughly simplified as follows;

```
SELECT Supplier.SupplierName, POHeader.PODate, POHeader.PORef, POLine.LineID, SUM(Subquery.Val)
FROM Supplier INNER JOIN POHeader ON POheader.supplier = Supplier.SupplierID
    INNER JOIN POLine ON POLine.HeaderID = POHeader.PO_ID
    INNER JOIN Subquery on Subquery.POLine = POLine.Line_ID
GROUP BY Supplier.SupplierName, POHeader.PODate, POHeader.PORef, POLine.Line_ID
```

I want a grand total at the bottom, *without* a bunch of subtotals dotted in throughout the report - therefore I don't think I can use `ROLLUP`. The `Subquery` in there is of course a sub query and in the real thing there will be twelve of them and all pretty complex, so I want to avoid a `UNION` just to total everything up if at all possible. Is there any other way I can put a Grand total row at the bottom of the report without subtotals?

Not completely sure of the SQL version but if it helps, google tells me *Microsoft SQL Server Express or SQL Server Standard can be used with OrderWise*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT Supplier.SupplierName, POHeader.PODate, POHeader.PORef, POLine.LineID, SUM(Subquery.Val)
FROM Supplier INNER JOIN
     POHeader
     ON POheader.supplier = Supplier.SupplierID JOIN
     POLine
     ON POLine.HeaderID = POHeader.PO_ID JOIN
     Subquery 
     ON Subquery.POLine = POLine.Line_ID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (Supplier.SupplierName, POHeader.PODate, POHeader.PORef, POLine.Line_ID), () )
```